# Setting baseline and range of barchart in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

I'm drawing a barchart representing the homicide rate in the U.S.A.. 
I'm trying to truncate this chart by setting the baseline at > 0 but the code:

```
    var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Intentional homicide rate per 100,000 population, by country/territory (2000-2013) in the US',
        subtitle: 'Intentional homicide is defined as unlawful death purposefully inflicted on a person by another person',
        hAxis: {title: 'Year'},
        vAxis: {
              title: 'Rate per 100,000', 
              viewWindow:{
                max:20,
                min:2
              },
        // ticks: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100] 
        },
      }
    };
```

doesn't do its job and shows the whole range contrarily to my aim.

[This](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fw9C70KFthLQ40iXanTK?p=preview) is the complete code of the chart.
What did I mistake?

The same procedure works with an area chart ([Pluckr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/8lU9fjRHLQjP5xI2PCBf?p=preview))... how come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't proper, as stated in other answers.

You need to use the function `google.charts.Bar.convertOptions` when working with material charts. [Source](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#creating-material-bar-charts) (scroll down a bit, or ctrl + f for convertOptions).

You're currently drawing the chart with

```
chart.draw(data, options);
```

while the correct way would be

```
chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
```

[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tltMMXyd5V5MWc7ao3BV?p=preview)

(This is also why it's working with the area chart.. That's not a material chart).